# Make 3 different sites a wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I am going to merge **3 different sites into one multisite.** One site has Enfold theme installed (and it would be a master site), two other is on my own theme.

I know how to turn on a multisite etc. but my question is: what is the best way to copy these 2 sites into master's wordpress installation? I have different themes and plugins installed on my sites and I am afraid it could be problematic. Also I can't loose any information or styles.

Will be glad for any guide or link.

Regards!

Comment: I think the codex should be sufficient https://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite

Comment: Thanks, hope that would work as expected:)